# Return group frequency, count of values meeting condition, and ratio, by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Given the data.table below, how can I get the desired result? The 'grpFreq' column contains the count of each 'grp' in the original data.table, the 'posCnt' column contains the count of positive numbers in 'val' for each group, and the 'ratio' column is posCnt/grpFreq.

```
library( data.table )

DT <- data.table( grp = c(1,2,5,5,5,5,3,4,4,4), val = c(-1,0,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1) )
DT

    grp val
 1:   1  -1
 2:   2   0
 3:   5   1
 4:   5   1
 5:   5  -1
 6:   5   1
 7:   3   1
 8:   4  -1
 9:   4  -1
10:   4   1
```

to this desired result:

```
# grp   grpFreq posCnt  ratio
# 1     1       0       0
# 2     1       0       0
# 3     1       1       1
# 4     3       1       0.33
# 5     4       3       0.75
```

The following attempts get me part of the way. First, a count of the values > 0 from the 'val' column are in the rightmost column here (the '-1' and '0' columns are not needed):

```
dcast(DT, grp~val, length)

   grp -1 0 1
1:   1  1 0 0
2:   2  0 1 0
3:   3  0 0 1
4:   4  2 0 1
5:   5  1 0 3
```

Second, this gets me a frequency count of each 'grp', but not in the same form as above:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(count = n())

     grp   val count
   (dbl) (dbl) (int)
1      1    -1     1
2      2     0     1
3      5     1     4
4      5     1     4
5      5    -1     4
6      5     1     4
7      3     1     1
8      4    -1     3
9      4    -1     3
10     4     1     3
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!!

Comment: I suggest performing all of your calculations as part of a `dplyr` pipeline. The problem with your `dplyr` code is that you `group_by(grp)`, but you don't `summarize` over the groups, you just `mutate`. `mutate` will return the same number of rows in your dataset, not a single entity for each value in `grp`. That is why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: Also, not sure if there's a specific reason for creating your example data with `data.table`. You could just as easily used `data.frame()` or `data_frame()` from the `dplyr` package. Just saying in case you think you need to use `data.table` library just to create your sample data.

Comment: Hi @StevenMortimer. Thank you for the missing link. Couldn't get my head around the syntax at the time but it makes sense now. So the result of each element is available to subsequent elements in the pipeline, nice. My data happens to be in a data.table hence its use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DT <- data.table( grp = c(1,2,5,5,5,5,3,4,4,4), val = c(-1,0,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1) )

DT %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(grpFreq  = length(grp), 
            posCnt = sum(val > 0)) %>%
  mutate(ratio = posCnt/grpFreq)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
    grp grpFreq posCnt     ratio
  <dbl>   <int>  <int>     <dbl>
1     1       1      0 0.0000000
2     2       1      0 0.0000000
3     3       1      1 1.0000000
4     4       3      1 0.3333333
5     5       4      3 0.7500000
```

Comment: Hi Steven. Thank you for the dplyr version. @Imo answered first so flagging it as the solution, though this here is equivalent when used on my data set of 50k rows and 3k columns.

Comment: Just so you're aware the order of proposed answers depends on the number of upvotes or down votes, not when someone answered the question chronologically. I answered 15 minutes before @lmo but it's listed lower because it has been upvoted fewer times. You should flag the answer that best answers your question regardless of order on the page.

Comment: @SteveMortimer Thanks for the heads-up. These 2 answers are equivalent for my current use. I used chronological order only to break the tie. Apologies for remembering that backwards. Now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In `data.table`, you could do

```
DT[order(grp), .(grpFreq=.N, posCnt=sum(val > 0), ratio=sum(val > 0) / .N), by=grp]
```

in one call or better use a chain and `:=`

```
DT[order(grp), .(grpFreq=.N, posCnt=sum(val > 0)), by=grp][, ratio := posCnt / grpFreq][]
```

The second method is probably preferable as it reduces the number of calculations and assignment with `:=` is memory efficient. The `[]` at the end of the second call is not necessary in practice, but tells `data.table` to print the results to screen.

Both return

```
   grp grpFreq posCnt     ratio
1:   1       1      0 0.0000000
2:   2       1      0 0.0000000
3:   3       1      1 1.0000000
4:   4       3      1 0.3333333
5:   5       4      3 0.7500000
```

Comment: Hi @Imo. My code wasn't even close to this! Thank you for the clarification. To decipher the syntax I used  the DataCamp cheat sheet at [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf)